# Child theme template value for style.css for parent in different folder

Tags: child-theme

I am making a child theme in the `.../wp-content/themes/` folder however the parent theme that I am building on is in the `.../wp-content/plugins/` directory.  I am able to import the parent `style.css` file using a directory path but when I try to do the same for the Template value, it does not work.  Similarly, the simple name of the parent theme folder does not work either, presumably because the parent theme is in a different directory.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It was an issue of versioning, where the site needed to be refreshed again after saving the child style.css file.  The solution was to include the Template value like any other child theme and adjust the import command using a full path instead of a relative ".../" preceding the parent style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parent theme's non-standard location was correctly added with [`register_theme_directory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_theme_directory), and I am pretty sure it must have been, then functions like [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) and [`get_template_directory_uri`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) should work.

## Reference

http://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories#Themes